# Trigger an event if the collided object has the tag "Player"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have a trigger zone around a spider terrarium in my game and would like that to trigger the spider's animation when the player walks into the trigger, here is my attempt, but it is returning an error "The name 'col' does not exist in the current context". Thanks in advance!

```
public class Spider: MonoBehaviour 
{
    Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            anim.SetTrigger("spider");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from the parameter being `collision`, but using `col`, what is the error?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You named your Collision as collision, not col. So of course col doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

> The name 'col' does not exist in the current context

This error message already explains the problem: There's no variable called `col` in your code. The correct name is `collision` as defined in the method parameter.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("spider");

    }
}
```

should be

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("spider");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the colliding object has been given the name `collision`, so you need to use that name when checking the variable:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("spider");

    }
}
```